# Using CoffeeScript, how would I go about creating an AngularJS controller that has ngSanitize?

Tags: angularjs, coffeescript

I am trying to create an Angular controller that has ngSanitize like in the example here https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize/service/$sanitize

But I am not sure how to do this in CoffeeScript.

In the example in the docs, here's how a controller is being created with ngSanitize.

```
angular.module('sanitizeExample', ['ngSanitize'])
       .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', '$sce', function($scope, $sce)
```

Here is my current controller written in CoffeeScript:

```
app = angular.module 'example'
app.controller 'exampleController', ($scope, widgetSrv)
```

How would I add ngSanitize to this?

Answer (score 0):

Change the second line of your controller to:

```
app = angular.module 'example', ['ngSanitize']
```

Comment: I've tried this but it seems to break the entire page.